# numpy.savetxt() outputs very large files

Tags: python, arrays, file-io, numpy

I am using numpy.savetxt() to write a numpy array to a csv file, but the file that is generated is VERY large. For example, if I create a zeros array:

```
import numpy

test = numpy.zeros((10000,10000), dtype=numpy.float32)
numpy.savetxt('C:/datatest.csv',test,delimiter=',')
```

I would expect the file to be around 10,000*10,000*4 bytes (400 MB) large. (This is also what `test.nbytes` returns). However, the file is 2.3 GB large. Is there a reason for the large file size? I looked through the numpy documentation, there doesn't seem to be a way to specify the variable type when writing to a file. I tried other file types/delimiters, but get the same results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The size of the native datatype differs from the size of the string representation of the datatype.

[`numpy.savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) has a `fmt` argument that defaults to `'%.18e'`, which formats each of your zeros as `0.000000000000000000e+00`.  That is 24 characters per item plus one for the delimiter.

To get a smaller file you can change the format (beware of losing significant digits) or use [`numpy.save`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html#numpy.save) to save in binary or [`numpy.savez`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html#numpy.savez) to save as a compressed archive.

Comment: It's worth emphasizing that, whatever the format, `savetxt` saves the data in *string* form.  The OP seems to think that each float32 value will be saved as 4 bytes in some binary format, but that's not the case.

Comment: It's also very important, that all zeros in this file all need 1 or 2 bytes, depending on the encoding. The float32 needs 4 bytes for the whole number. (all 18 digits)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, changing the fmt option reduced the size!

Comment: @sam: If you don't need your results to be human readable, a binary format may be better.